# Do hollowbody basses feedback as much as hollow body guitars?

Tags: electric-bass-guitar

With a hollow body electric guitar, you'll have to manage (control or suppress) the feedback at any amplification level loud enough to be heard over a rock and roll drummer.

Is the same true (in general) for hollow body electric basses?
Mostly, I'm concerned with whether you have to use your hand or arm to control the feedback.

Comment: Truth be told I don't think anything beats rolling the volume off when you can. Otherwise I'd just use my hand to kill any feedback. Part of me does say though that if the drummer is so loud that you're having to run your rig to the point of it feeding back seriously you should ask them to keep it back a bit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - any hollow body guitar will feed back much more than a solid one - the difference between the bass and the guitar will just be which frequencies are going to feed back most.

You can use your hand to control feedback, but other options include:

- Using an equaliser to roll off the frequencies you find feeding back too much
- Moving further away from, or closer to the speaker

Answer (score 1):

If it's anything like an acoustic bass I used to own, yes. You don't specify if it's the note you're playing or one of the open strings. These need to be damped by spare fingers or part of the plucking hand. If it's the played note, a change of tone, moving away from the speaker or as above, playing less loudly are your options.